# LWJGL timer not working?

Tags: java, lwjgl, timedelta, delta

I keep getting a lot of "Delta: 0.0"s in my console and ever few lines I get something like "Delta: 9.999275207519531E-4", what's happening?

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    float lastTime = 0.0f;
    timer.resume();
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested())
    {
        timer.tick();
        System.out.println("Delta: " + (timer.getTime() - lastTime));

        lastTime = timer.getTime();

        Display.update();
    }

    Display.destroy();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever use java's Timer class in your game loops.  It isn't precise enough to use reliably.  Instead, check out [this](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0) link to see a couple of reliable game loops written in java.

Answer (score 0):

One little note, just a warning. Your timing mechanism is flawed a bit.
Considering this code runs line by line as it is written, you'll "loose" time. This

```
System.out.println("Delta: " + (timer.getTime() - lastTime));
lastTime = timer.getTime();
```

code does the following:
1. Getting current time.
2. Doing some math.
3. Calling String constructor.
4. Performing String concatenation.
5. Writing current time to the `lastTime` variable.

Note that *current time* in the **1** and **5** cases are different. That means that this time is "lost" from the "Delay: xx" output.

If you continue to use `(timer.getTime() - lastTime)` technics in your code for the purpose of getting time passed from the previous iteration, you will surely run into problem where different events thinks that time passed from the previous iteration is different. I recommend you to use the following code for timing:

```
private double delta;
private long timing;

public void updateTime()
{
    long newTime = System.nanoTime();
    this.delta = (newTime - this.timing) / 1_000_000_000.0;
    this.timing = newTime;
}

public double getDelta() {
    return this.delta;
}
```

where `updateTime()` is called once per cycle and `getDelta()` is called every time you want to get time passed from the previous iteration.